# how i can replace or remove special character from a file before upload to a database and before move to a directory?

Tags: php, pdo

how i can replace or remove special character from a file before upload to a database and before move to a directory?

this what i have

```
$images = array();
$dt1=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

foreach ($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $val) {

$file_name = $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];


$upload_dir = "pdfs/";
$upload_image = $upload_dir . $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key], $upload_image)) {
$images[] = $upload_image;

$objetPdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=ifsi', 'root', '');


$pdoStat1 = $objetPdo->prepare('INSERT INTO pdfpublic VALUES(NULL ,:nomPdf,:pdf_file,:dateUpload)');

$pdoStat1->bindValue(':nomPdf', $_POST['NomPDF'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat1->bindValue(':pdf_file', $_FILES['images']['name'][$key], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdoStat1->bindValue(':dateUpload', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), PDO::PARAM_STR);

$pdoStat1->execute();


}

}
```

Comment: I usually use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) ... simple and fast.

Comment: i did but negative resault , it doesn't working

Comment: Modify your post and show what you tried that didn't work along with any error messages if there were any.

Comment: i did but only in the directory that i store my pdfs files not in my mysql database i live in france so i need to remove every specail character of file basenme before uploading to database

Comment: I posted an answer that shows how you might use `str_replace` as well as moving your PDO instance to before you start to loop since it only needs to be done once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `str_replace` function to replace any characters that you do not want to be included in file names.

```
$objetPdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306;dbname=ifsi', 'root', '');

foreach ($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $val) {

    //
    // Add or remove characters in the array below to change
    // what is or is not removed from the file name
    //
    $file_name = str_replace(array('-',' ','.','(',')',',','$','*'),'',$_FILES['images']['name'][$key]);

    $upload_image = 'pdfs/' . $file_name;

    if (move_uploaded_file($file_name,$upload_image)) {

        $images[] = $upload_image;

        $pdoStat1 = $objetPdo->prepare('INSERT INTO pdfpublic VALUES(NULL ,:nomPdf,:pdf_file,:dateUpload)');

        $pdoStat1->bindValue(':nomPdf', $_POST['NomPDF'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdoStat1->bindValue(':pdf_file', $file_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pdoStat1->bindValue(':dateUpload', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $pdoStat1->execute();

    }  // end of if move file worked

}  // end of foreach
```

Comment: Warning: str_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 2 given in C:\wamp64\www\IFSIWeb\pdf\adddddd.php on line 11 the error i get

Comment: Fixed ... missed a comma

Comment: I left some changes for you in my answer but you apparently didn't pick up on that so I modified my answer again and changed the use of the `FILES` array directly to use the `$file_name` variable instead. See if the changes work for you please.

Comment: no it doesn't work even worse it don't store in my database nor in directory

Comment: Nothing in what I gave you would have caused those issues. Update your question with a copy of what you are using now.